# Tkinter: Upload 2 files

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I wrote a tkinter script so that when the user chooses the 2 files and clicks upload files, the first file is read and stored into `content` and the second files is read and stored into `content2`, so that it can continue with the rest of the code.

When I add `print (content)` in `def Uploadfiles()`, it prints the file content, however, it doesn't store the content for the rest of the rest of the code to run. See Error Screenshot.

How can I fix this so that the rest of the code would run based on the uploaded files?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('400x200')


def open_file1():
    file_path = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('All files', '*')])
    if file_path is not None:
        global file1
        file1 = file_path.read()

def open_file2():
    file_path = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('All Files', '*')])
    if file_path is not None:
        global file2
        file2 = file_path.read()

def uploadFiles():
    content = file1
    content2 = file2
    ws.destroy()

adhar = Label(
    ws,
    text='Upload File 1 '
)
adhar.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)

adharbtn = Button(
    ws,
    text='Choose File',
    command=lambda: open_file1()
)
adharbtn.grid(row=0, column=1)

dl = Label(
    ws,
    text='Upload File  '
)
dl.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)

dlbtn = Button(
    ws,
    text='Choose File ',
    command=lambda: open_file2()
)
dlbtn.grid(row=1, column=1)

upld = Button(
    ws,
    text='Upload Files',
    command=uploadFiles
)
upld.grid(row=3, columnspan=3, pady=10)

ws.mainloop()

def parse_value(txt):
    reclines = []
    for line in txt.split('\n'):
        if ':' not in line:
            if reclines:
                yield reclines
                reclines = []
        else:
            reclines.append(line)

def parse_fields(reclines):
    res = {}
    for line in reclines:
        key, val = line.strip().rstrip(',').split(':', 1)
        res[key.strip()] = val.strip()
    return res

res = []
for rec in parse_value(content):
    res.append(parse_fields(rec))

res2 = []
for rec in parse_value(content2):
    res2.append(parse_fields(rec))

df = pd.json_normalize(res)
df2 = pd.json_normalize(res2)

df
df2
```

Screenshot of the Output Window and Error

[image: Output Window with Error]

Comment: You haven't shown the code that calls `parse_value`

Comment: Your posted code does not have those code segments in the image, it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: @acw1668 added now

Comment: `content` is a local variable inside `uploadFiles()` so it is not accessible outside the function.  Make it a global variable like `file1` and `file2`.  However code beyond `mainloop()` will only be executed after closing/destroying the root window.

Comment: Why don't you just use `file1` and `file2` instead of `content` and `content2`?